# redefine \maketitle

Tags: titles

I am using a template which defines `\maketitle` to include the date, in addition to the author and the title. I cannot find the file in which this is defined, but there is the following comment in the `.tex` template which I am modifying:

```
\maketitle          % Use the \author, \title and \date info
```

I would like to redefine the command to include just the `\author` and `\title` info. Any suggestions on how to do this?

I want to redefine `\maketitle` in my `.tex` file. The original definition could be in any package that I might be using.

Comment: Without seeing the definition, it's impossible to give sensible advice.

Comment: If you want to create the titlepage completely on your own, you can have a look at [How to customize a titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907).

Comment: `\maketitle` often is defined in your documentclass. Which one are you using?

Comment: Wat hapens if you have more than one author??

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As you indicated you have no clue where your `\maketitle` is defined. Lets take TeX to find out the definition:

Replace

```
\maketitle          % Use the \author, \title and \date info
```

with

```
\meaning\maketitle
```

This line will give you the definition of `\maketitle` currently in effect. Chances are high that this will result in some bookkeeping operations and then calling another macro, often called `\@maketitle` or similar as in WChargin's answer. We thus have to find out what `\@maketitle` (or however it is called) does. So add

```
\makeatletter\meaning\@maketitle\makeatother
```

The `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`-pair is necessary to make LaTeX cope with the `@` in `\@maketitle`.

With this information you can proceed as described win WChargin's answer. Lets assume you get the definition WChargin posted you could alter it as below (adding `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` again because of the `@`)

```
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    %{\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
```

You will observe that this is exactly equivalent to what WChargin wrote.

Comment: your suggestion worked exceedingly well, so thanks for the same. there was a minor typo in the last \fi, and I commented it out, because tex was cribbing.

Comment: Btw, I found another link with a similar problem, which has a different method, so sharing it for what it is worth: http://physical-thought.blogspot.com.au/2008/01/removing-author-and-date-items-from.html Coincidentally, I tried editing the code snippet provided in the link to add the author information as well, but could not get it working. My code change (which does not work) is as follows: \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
  {\LARGE \@title \par}%
\end{center}%
\begin{center}%
  {\SMALL \@author \par}%
\end{center}%
\par} \makeatother

Comment: btw, I get the following when I substitute \maketitle as you suggested: macro:-.gnewpage gnull gvskip 2emgbegin .center.glet
gfootnote gthanks .gLARGE g@title gpar .gvskip 1.5em.glarge
glineskip .5emgbegin .tabular.[t].c.g@author gend .tabular
.gpar .gvskip 1em.glarge g@date .gend .center.gpar
gvskip 1.5em

Comment: I haven't seen `\meaning` before. Is it just `\show` but actually typesetting the macro? Why is this preferable to `\show`?

Comment: Imho `\show` has the advantage of giving a copy-pasteable output in the log-file, which is easy to transfer into your tex-file and is already (more or less) nicely formatted. `\meaning` on the other hand has the advantage that one does not need to navigate a "clueless" person through the log-file. Apart from that: Ask the gurus.

Answer (score 17):

Well, the simplest way to do this is

```
\date{}
```

which will use an empty date. But there will be an extra space.

I don't have your style file, so I'll use `article` as an example.
To find the definition of `\maketitle`, you could either execute `\show\maketitle` from an interactive TeX run, or you could look it up in the package file (with extension .cls for a class, and .sty for a style).
The latter is probably better because you get nicer formatting and indentation.

To get the path to a package, say, class article.cls, run `kpsewhich article.cls` at a terminal.

Thereafter, from `article.cls` (line 213):

```
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
```

From this, we can see that it's the `\@maketitle` command that does the actual typesetting.
That's defined on the next line.

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\fi
```

So you can just redefine it, remove the line you don't want, and you're done.

---

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
    \def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    %\vskip 1em%
    %{\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\fi
\makeatother

\title{MWE}
\author{You}
\date{Today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I metioned, I do not know where this is defined....so ideally I would like to add a new definition overriding the existing one....how can I do this?

Comment: Well, *you* may not know where it is defined, but obviously TeX does, or it wouldn't be able to compile. So open up your style file, search for `\maketitle`, and follow an analogous procedure.

Comment: @Vinod Please see my edit.

Comment: I am not sure where the .sty file is located....in fact, I am not very familiar with tex and I see only the .tex and .bib files in my directory....so I want to add a new definition in my .tex file overriding the existing one

Comment: @Vinod Somewhere in your preamble, you must have a `\usepackage` command to load your style file. Note the name of the package; I'll call it `foo`. Then, run `kpsewhich foo.sty` at a terminal and you'll get the path to the `sty` file. Example: `kpsewhich amsmath.sty` yields `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty`.

Comment: I have the following packages included in my .tex file \usepackage{float}  % this is to place figures where requested!
\usepackage{times}  % this uses fonts which will look nice in PDF format
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  % needed for the figures
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref} but I cannot get the path for any of these by running the command that you suggested....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19310/discussion-between-vinod-and-wchargin).