# How to change font and font size of title in a class file?

Tags: fontsize, document-classes

I'm newbie in making LaTeX classes and this is my first attempt. I'm trying to create a class where I select the font type (Roboto) and its size for different sections of the file. I've tried the following:

```
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesClass{idletechs}[some text]

    \newcommand{\headlinecolor}{\normalcolor}

    \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
    \ProcessOptions\relax

    \LoadClass[12pt]{report}

    \renewcommand{\maketitle}{ \fontsize{72}{80}\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}%
    \fontshape{sl}\selectfont\headlinecolor
    \@title ]
    }
```

However, this applies the font size on the whole document and not just on the title. Could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Put the font change inside a group. E.g., `\begingroup\fontsize{72}{80}...\@title\endgroup`. (Is the `]` a typo?)

Comment: Great it works. ] was a typo. I copied these code from different sources and don't have a good clue what each command within \renewcommand does, for example what does \fontshape{sl} do and  which font is \selectfont. could you help me with that? In addition if I want to use the font "Roboto", should I pt in in \fontfamily{}? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to make a class?  You can always just input an entire preamble from another file.

Comment: `\selectfont` is the thing that actually changes to the font you've selected using the preceding commands like `\fontfamily{phv}`. You should ask your follow up questions as new questions though. That way more people will see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete example using the `article` class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\headlinecolor{\normalcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\maketitle{%
    \begingroup
    \centering
    \fontsize{72}{80}% 72pt on 80pt leading
    \fontfamily{phv}% Helvetica
    \fontseries{b}% Bold
    \fontshape{sl}% Slanted
    \selectfont
    \headlinecolor
    \@title
    \par
    \vskip1in
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\title{Foo Bar}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some other text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the Roboto font instead, then the easiest way is to `\usepackage{roboto}` (or `\RequirePackage{roboto}` inside a class definition) and just use standard font commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{roboto}
\newcommand\headlinecolor{\normalcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\maketitle{%
    \begingroup
    \centering
    \fontsize{72}{80}% 72pt on 80pt leading
    \roboto % Roboto
    \bfseries % Bold
    \slshape % Slanted
    \headlinecolor
    \@title
    \par
    \vskip1in
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\title{Foo Bar}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some other text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I really wouldn't do it this way. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216098/redefine-maketitle) for some suggestions.