# Why is this tabular environment necessary?

Tags: titles

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216098/redefine-maketitle) I  discovered that the definition of `\maketitle` is:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\fi
```

My question is: why is `\author` typeset in a `tabular` environment when the title and date aren't?

Comment: Because of the alignment in case of having more than one author. It's easier. `\and` is a cunning way of `\endtabular...\tabular`

Comment: Also, is \maketitle necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to supplement this with the definition of `\and`:

```
\end{tabular}\hskip 1em plus .17fil\begin {tabular}[t]{c}
```

So if you specify

```
\author{A. Uthor \\ Here University \and W. Riter \\ There University}
```

the author part will become (reformatted and with `\and` replaced for clarity)

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
  A. Uthor \\ Here University
\end{tabular}
\hskip 1em plus .17fil
\begin {tabular}[t]{c}
  W. Riter \\ There University
\end{tabular}\par
```

Thus you get *two* distinct `tabular`, separated by some horizontal spacing. If only one author is expected, then `tabular` wouldn't be necessary, but this is frequently not the case.