# Finding the result of commands such as \show or \meaning in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

So I'm looking up solutions for modifying the output of the command \maketitle. I arrived at this great post [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216098/redefine-maketitle). I'm using Texmaker on a Windows PC, and I would like to use commands such as \show and \meaning to understand how some commands are defined. But I don't know where to look for the output in Texmaker when using \show or \meaning.

Is the output in the log file? Where in the log file?

Thanks

Comment: `\show` is exactly the same as an error message so it comes on the terminal and in the log at the point corresponding to the place you put it in the source, the interaction is just as if you had an error there, with the same `?` prompt, just that the message is not really an error message but requested information.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I'm learning how to read the log file now, I'll let you know if I am able to sort it out.